# How to fix this symfony permission error?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

On my live site I'm facing this problem when I load my browser:

> ContextErrorException in FileProfilerStorage.php line 158: Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/var/www/html/var/cache/dev/profiler/c9/73/fb73c9):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

How can I fix this problem at the live site?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: i checked out this but this is not related error what i fixing for.

Comment: How cannot be related?

Comment: Are you using Nginx or Apache?

Comment: I am using Apache ,and i am also try http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html link but could not solve it

Comment: Provide the `User` and `Group` parameters of `httpd.conf`, and the output of `ll /your/symfony_dir/var`

Comment: run this command from your project root folder: 
`sudo chmod -R 777 var/cache`

Comment: Grammar and syntax fixes.

Answer (score 14):

Run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/cache
```

in your project directory, later clear the cache using

```
app/console cache:clear
```

An reset permissions again

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/cache
```

Every time the cache is cleared reset permissions of folder cache to avoid this type of problems with created files during the clear process.

Note: `app/console` could be `bin/console`

Comment: Hmmm, no this doesn't seem right at all. You should be able to clear the cache at the CLI and still have a working application without manually updating permissions. This does work as a workaround, but it's not a solution.

Comment: For Symfony 4 use this to clear cache: `php bin/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 2):

You should try this set of permissions which are recommended by AWS:

First you need through a terminal go to your project directory and run the command:

```
ls -las
```

where you will see something like:

[image]

Note the columns where it says: **webapp**, that tells you which user/group have access to your project, so what you need to do now is go to your apache config file (normally you can find it in linux on: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) once you opened the file by using vi, vim or you favourite text editor you should look for **User & Group** and ensure that the user/group is the same one that the one from the image above and ensure that the user belongs to the group you have had configured or set on your httpd.conf then you should run the following command to apply the right set of permissions for users & groups by doing:

```
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

and now it should work fine.

Note that /var/www is an example of where you could host your project but it depends on your configuration in the file httpd.conf

Hope this helps.